# Is there a limit to Google Webmasters Tools Api when fetching for crawl issues

Tags: api, google-search-console

I was tasked to create an admin tool to download crawl issues for one of our sites. I used the code from https://github.com/eyecatchup/GWT_CrawlErrors-php.

The only modification I made was to use OAuth 2.0 for authentication since circumstances do not allow me to have access to the webmasters account.

My implementation worked fine and I was already able to download the csv files but cross-checking results between the api and the web tool reveals that the api returns only about **16K+** entries while the web tool has about **40K+**. I also tested this using Google's [OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) and the results show **16K+** entries also.

Is there any limit imposed on google web masters tools api that is not mentioned in their [docs](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol#Crawl)?